# How to format the value in a edit field in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, formatting, formhelper

The price is a float value, and I want to display it like `1.000,00` instead of `1000.00`

I know I can use an afterfind callback to change the value, but I will need the original value to do some math.

Is there any callback, like symfony data transformes in cakephp or do I need to use the callback, to create a second field with the formatted value.

Any other options?

```
echo $this->Form->input('price'); // Price is a float
```

In the docs and api for FormHelper I could not find anything about this.

Comment: cakephp have a function that displays the float as currency but it wont change it back... I sugest that you manage inputs as floats, or you will need to do a function to know if people use the correct format, i had this problem before, so i limit the number to be like 1234,56 or 1234 and in the controller do a string replace of , for . so it will be a float, and in the index i use cake currency format to display Bs. 1.234,56 or Bs. 1.234

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using a behavior to "translate" from and to the database.
there a tons of them out there. "numeric", "decimal" etc should be the names for it

if you google for those behaviors you find sth like
http://float-dot-fixable-behavior.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/float_dot_fixable.php

it can easy be enhanced (both ways):

- from  db: . to ,
- to db: , to .

Comment: The thing is: I can not just change . to , because I need to do some math with the values. Say a shopping cart, `price * qty`. If in a behaviour I changed . to , I would need to change it back when calculating the total price for example. I guess my best shot is to have tow fields one for displaying and one for calculations?

Comment: you can always do the same thing in such a behavior and store it in another array key. what you are mixing up here is model data and presentation data, i guess. you should be doing those things in the view or controller. use a helper for this and output it then in the shopping cart view. there is no need to convert it anywhere else before that.